# outputting text in XQuery using saxon9he: how do I get "<" and ">" created in the output themselves, not escaped?

Tags: xquery, saxon

My XQuery script:

```
declare namespace output = "http://​www.​w3.​org/​2010/​xslt-​xquery-​ser​iali​zati​on"; 
declare option output:method "text"; 

for $row in all/row
return ('"<row>","',data($row),'"&#xA;')
```

My XML:

```
<all>
  <row>one</row>
  <row>two</row>
  <row>three</row>
</all>
```

My command line:

```
java -cp …/saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Query '!omit-xml-declaration=yes' -s:./trouble-with-output-escaping.xml -q:./trouble-with-output-escaping.xqy
```

My output as created by saxon9he:

```
"&lt;row&gt;"," one "
 "&lt;row&gt;"," two "
 "&lt;row&gt;"," three "
```

I actually want to have output like this:

```
"<row>","one"
"<row>","two"
"<row>","three"
```

During my web investigation I came across XSLT's disable-output-escaping.
I thought: if XQuery had that, that might help.

Update/0:

Actually nothing (visible) was wrong with the above XQuery script.
The namespace declaration above needs to get replaced by this one:

```
declare namespace output = "http://www.w3.org/2010/xslt-xquery-serialization";
```

Looks the same, but it isn't, as Michael pointed out.

Having completed this, the above is an example of how to create text output using XQuery.

In some other place Michael showed, how get rid of the space (0x20), that is being used to separate the lines, i.e. the space character preceding lines 2 to the end:

```
string-join(…,"")
```

where "…" would be the entire FLWOR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's doing the right thing if you set output method "text" from the command line, that is

```
java net.sf.saxon.Query -q:test.xquery -s:test.xml -t !method=text
```

but you had me baffled as to why setting the serialization options from within the query isn't working. Looking at it in the debugger, though, I see that your URI, which looks like

http://​www.​w3.​org/​2010/​xslt-​xquery-​ser​iali​zati​on

actually contains several occurrences of decimal 8203, hex 200B, which is a zero-width space. This means the URI doesn't match the serialization output URI, and "declare option" with an unrecognized URI is ignored.

Comment: your command line causes an exception here:  
"Invalid value for serialization method: must be xml, html, xhtml, text, or a QName in '{uri}local' form"

Comment: I typed the URI manually (as shown), and it worked – as you explained.
(I had copied the URI before from an e-book, and I had to remove several weird hyphens anyway.) Big, big thank you!!!

Comment: Just a reminder that the SO convention is not to say thank-you, but to mark the answer as accepted. The green tick is much easier for future visitors to spot.

Comment: I have no idea, why "!method=text" works for you but not for me.

Comment: @JochenHayek in some shells the "!" needs to be escaped as `\!`, but the error message seems surprising.